# Can the conflict between the use of a <BASE> tag with a relative href and <a href='#'> be resolved?

Tags: html, url, base-tag

When using a  tag with a relative url, e.g.

```
<base href="app/" />
```

The use of any `<a href='#'>` throughout the site causes the href on the anchor tag to be rewritten according to the relative path, which then becomes clickable to an invalid url.

I can replace `<a href='#'>` with `<a href='javascript:void(0)'>` and then the browser ignores rewriting the target url according to the prefix specified in the base tag - and it works as expected (doing nothing and causing no navigation.

But I was wondering if there was a more general way to cause the '#' url target to be excluded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A `base` element with `href` attribute affects all URL-valued attributes, by definition. Your page probably needs a redesign. The `base` element as such is seldom a good idea, and `a` elements that are not meant to be links are even worse.

Comment: Agreed about the redesign for these two issues, just needed some independent confirmation. We're removing the <base> tag entirely but it will take some time, sounds like removing our use of the <a href='#'> entirely for non-action anchors will solve it in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `<a>` tags for anything but actual links.

If you want to have a clickable element that doesn't navigate, use `<button type="button"></button>` and style it how you'd like. After all, what you're looking for here is a button, not a link.